# Missing library files in PyInstaller with FFMPEG

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I'm quite new to PyInstaller, but I'm trying to get it to build an exe from a little set of scripts I've written. Unfortunately, I use a couple of different modules, like FFMPEG (through FFPyPlayer). When I try to build I get:

> 360570 WARNING: lib not found: avformat-58.dll dependency of c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\player\player.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
>
> 360572 WARNING: lib not found: SDL2_mixer.dll dependency of c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\player\player.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
>
> 360573 WARNING: lib not found: swresample-3.dll dependency of c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\player\player.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
>
> 360578 WARNING: lib not found: avdevice-58.dll dependency of c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\player\player.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
>
> 360580 WARNING: lib not found: swscale-5.dll dependency of c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\player\player.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
>
> 360582 WARNING: lib not found: avfilter-7.dll dependency of c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\player\player.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
>
> 360583 WARNING: lib not found: postproc-55.dll dependency of c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\player\player.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
>
> 360584 WARNING: lib not found: avutil-56.dll dependency of c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\player\player.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
>
> 360586 WARNING: lib not found: avcodec-58.dll dependency of c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\ffpyplayer\player\player.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

I couldn't find these dlls, but I found them on the ffmpeg site and tried to point PyInstaller right at them using --paths, but it doesn't make a difference.

Does anyone have any suggestions? They'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out @djcmm476? I just hit this same problem and would love any tips you/others have.